# How to embed a search bar within a navigation bar in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to embed a search bar within a navigation bar so that when a navigation item is selected the search bar appears within the navigation bar.  I was searching for solutions online and I saw that some people just hide the navigation bar altogether and just use the search bar. That won't work for this project because I need to retain the back button (that automatically appears in navi bars when navigating to a new viewcontroller).  What I'm looking to create is something similar to twitters search bar on the top of their iOS app.  I've been doing most of my GUI work visually, so if there is a visual solution as well as a programming one I would prefer the visual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope, this example in Objective C will help you:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UITextField * textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 221, 25)];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = textField;
}
```